# What do I have to do to have a program I downloaded show up in "Search your computer and online resources"?

Tags: command-line, downloads, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio, and untared it in `/usr/local` as I read I should to avoid it eating `/home` space. Then I added the path to the `/bin` folder to the PATH variable, but I still can't execute it without going to `/usr/local/android-studio/bin` and executing `./studio.sh` from the shell.

Is there any way to make it show up in "Search your computer and online sources" like other programs I downloaded using `apt-get install`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to create a `.desktop` file.

This can be done manually as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/13758/367990).

Alternatively, it should be enough for most applications to run them and then right-click on their launcher icon. The appearing context menu should offer an option <kbd>Lock to launcher</kbd> or <kbd>Add to Dash</kbd> or similar.

Chose that and Ubuntu will try to automatically create an appropriate `.desktop` file that will make your application show up in the Dash. You may unlock it from the launcher again if you want to, it will remain in the Dash anyway.

Comment: ...and that solves the second half! :)

Answer (score 3):

This solves the first half of your question, but I'm not sure about the second half, or if the second half is simply there to help to solve the first half.

Try installing the run script to /usr/local/bin, like this:

`cd` to directory where Android Studio is installed

```
sudo install studio.sh /usr/local/bin/studio
```

Then you can run it with `studio` from any directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the file the permissions to execute?

`sudo chmod +x studio.sh`

or maybe you can try:

`sh studio.sh`

I have installed Android Studio last year and it all went fine, if this doesn't solve your problem, comment that I'll try to see other solutions :)